# Yii Passing an integer value to model->find('type',2)

Tags: sql, model, yii

I have a model called Person which has a integer value column.I need to find Persons who are a particular type. 
So I tried like this.

```
$proflist = CHtml::listData(Person::model()->find('type','2'),'id','firstname');
```

But no results showing up. I think the problem with 'type' column which is integer.

please can anyone help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should have to be

```
$proflist = CHtml::listData(Person::model()->find('type =2'),'id','firstname');
```

or

```
$proflist = CHtml::listData(Person::model()->findAllByAttributes(array('type' => '2')),'id','firstname');
```

Read more about method find()

[image: CActiveRecord find()]

You should learn more from Yii official document

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveRecord